# Email Spoofing / Missing SPF Record

Tags: email, record, spf, spoofing

I got this new security warning:

> The domain lacks a DNS SPF policy record. SPF policies must to be
>   applied on every domain (including subdomains) having either an A,
>   AAAA or MX record. What can happen? An attacker will be able to spoof
>   emails originating from the domain, allowing for phishing attacks or
>   other scams.

I dont know about it and i tried nothing to fix it..

..Can anybody help me out to fix this issue?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you even try to look up what this means? There is plenty of documentation on how to do this. You could start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and ask more targeted questions when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick, just use this [SPF Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/) to generate the DNS Records you need to bring your domain in compliance with that warning